# how to insert a string containing a link with a helper in meteor blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to insert a string that contains a link with a helper (or is there any better option to achieve this?) in meteor blaze.

So far blaze just gives back the link as normal text with the '' tags.

Does anyone have a good solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to get you started :

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> linkTemplate linkData}}
  {{#each links}}
    {{> linkTemplate}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="linkTemplate">
  <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
</template>

Links=new Meteor.Collection(null);
Links.insert({
  url:"https://www.google.com",
  title:"Google"
});

Template.parent.helpers({
  linkData:function(){
    return {
      url:"https://www.google.com",
      title:"Google"
    };
  },
  links:function(){
    return Links.find();
  }
});
```

If you want to render a string in a template that happens to contain a link, you would have to provide the HTML string as in

```
var string="A link to <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>.";
```

Then you can use the triple bracket syntax {{{helperReturningHTMLString}}} and it will work as expected, but I don't think it's good practice unless you're working with something like a WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: maybe my example wasn't good enough, but it's alright, the triple brackets was the solution ;) thank you! sorry I can't vote yet :'(